# Download chart data as (x, y) coordinates from a given mlflow plot

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, greasemonkey, mlflow

For a given ML-flow plot, I am wondering if it is possible to download the chart-data from the plot (x, y) coordinates corresponding to each point in the plot.

e.g. https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/_images/metrics-step.png
[image]

When points is set to "On", the line explicitly displays the values plotted, on mouse-over one can see the (x, y) values. I want to download these values which get displayed when Points is turned "On" as a csv file.

Is this possible to achieve via a greasemonkey scripts or any other UI tools?

Appreciate any pointers from the front-end engineers / UI experts.

p.s. Assume that I don't have access to the underlying database (server-side) used to store the data for populating the plots. Hence attempting to pull data via a greasemonkey script.